# Excel: Count cells with "Apple" only in rows that matches the name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet that counts the number of a particular occurrence on a row only when it matches the name.

```
       Col A       Col B    Col C    Col D
Row 1  **Jane**    Apple    Orange   Apple
Row 2  **Bob**     Orange   Apple    Orange
Row 3  **John**    Apple    Apple    Apple
Row 4  **Joe**     Orange   Apple    Apple
```

I was thinking *=IF(A:A=A2, COUNTIF($B$2:$D$4,"Apple"), "NULL")* will work but it's not giving the expected result.

The expected result in the above formula is 1

Comment: Why is the answer 1?

Comment: the name 'Jane' is in there only once, anyway, so a lot of formulas will deliver that result. Can you post a more representative data sample? '1' would also be the result for the other rows, right? Why 1? There are two apples on that row.

Comment: The answer should be '1' cos cell reference A2 is Bob and the word 'Apple appears just once in its row.

Comment: The idea of the formula is 'if A2 matches any of the names in Column A [if Bob matches any name in list {Jane, Bob, John, Joe}], count how many times Bob got "Apple"(Count the occurrences of Apple on Row 2).

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `SUMPRODUCT`, viz:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5="Bob")*($B$2:$D$5="Apple"))
```

To make it a bit more flexible, could do something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=F3)*($B$2:$D$5=G2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this works perfectly when I use it on small data but gives the "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas can not be evaluated." error message when I try using it on big data

Comment: Well what does "big" mean?

Comment: 200 rows and 160 columns. File size 97kb

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. I take it you have other things going on in your file. Any event code, lots of array formulae etc?

Comment: Conditioner formatting that changes cell shading colour based on cell value and formula reference to a different sheet in same workbook. _=SUMPRODUCT((General!$A:$A=Cover!A43)*((General!$B:$FZ="aaa")+(General!$B:$FZ="ooo")))_